# Need to change the "bundle_id" in "google-services.json" file in the android folder for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, xcode, firebase, bundle-identifier

In my Flutter app project,
The "bundle_id" that exists in the "google-services.json" is not the same as CFBundleIdentifier in info.plist and BUNDLE_ID in the "GoogleService-Info.plist".

- after changing the **bundle id** in the xcode
- and then run **flutterfire configure**
- nothing changes in the "google-services.json" file
- and still got the old **"bundle_id"**

"google-services.json"

```
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.example.xx" // need to change that 
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

- I tried to create another Apple App But also

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and here is how to fix it :

1. Go to APIs & Services > Credentials in Google Cloud https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Delete the OAuth 2.0 Client ID which contains your old bundle id.
3. Then run the `flutterfire configure` command again.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the Firebase Console.
2. Select your project.
3. Click on the gear icon next to "Project Overview" and select "Project settings".
4. Under the "Your apps" section, locate your iOS app and click on the pencil icon to edit its settings.
5. Update the "iOS bundle ID" field with your new bundle ID.
6. Save

After updating the bundle ID in Firebase Console, download the new "google-services.json" file and replace the old one in your project. This should update the bundle ID in the file, and you can proceed with your app development.

Comment: It's unable to change Bundle ID

Comment: you need to change it in firebase console. And then download, what do you mean by it ?

Comment: In my Flutter app project, the "bundle_id" that exists in the "google-services.json" is not the same as CFBundleIdentifier in info.plist and <key>BUNDLE_ID</key> in the "GoogleService-Info.plist".

Comment: Yes, this one under appinvite_service does not want to change for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your android/ios bundle id easily
add package `change_app_package_name`

1. run the package command
2. Open the firebase project
3. go to the project setting
4. delete the previous android part
5. run the firebase configuration command